# Configure Visual Studio Team Services Version Control to point to GitHub Enterprise

Tags: github, version-control, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, team-explorer

Our team is looking at leveraging the Visual Studio code review features through Team Explorer however it appears that Visual Studio Team Services does not have the capability to point push and pull directly to and from a GitHub Enterprise.

Is this true or is there a way to configure and ensure that any Git check-ins go to a Git Enterprise server?

Comment: How do you expect VS Online hosted by Microsoft to talk through your firewall?

Comment: My question is really around discovery and more so to clarify if there is anything in place that can enable the code review process through Visual Studio. We understand the complexities around technical aspects but it is to understand if anything else exists apart from cloning repositories.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to push your code into a Git repository associated with the same Team Project that your Work Items are in.

You can easily clone your GitHub repo and add/change the remote and Push to TFS / Team Services.

There is no value in having GitHub Enterprise if you are using Team Services.

You can also sync your code between GitHub and VSTS: https://nkdagility.com/open-source-vsts-tfs-github-better-devops/

Answer (score -1):

If you do have Visual Studio 2015, use the **GitHub extension for Visual Studio** which allows you to more easily connect and work directly with public/private GitHub project within Visual Studio. You can find more details on: [Announcing the GitHub Extension for Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/04/30/announcing-the-github-extension-for-visual-studio.aspx)

Considering that cloud hosted source code management is one of the major features, the role of VSO is somewhat diminished. Also keep in mind that Git uses the pull request model for code reviews which is somewhat different that the code review process modeled within Visual Studio.

Comment: This answer confused me.  Visual Studio Online code reviews are also based on pull requests when you are using Git repos in Visual Studio Online.

Comment: What type of code reviews VSO uses depends on which VCS you use. Pull requests are not available when using TFS with VSO. Second, VSO can use pull requests only when using VSO-Git and NOT GitHub.

Comment: Also as of now (although this is about to change), you cannot use VS to complete a pull request, it has to be done on the VSO portal. That combined with the earlier comment means if you do not use VSO-Git, you cannot use the pull-request model.

Comment: You can do pull requests within Visual Studio as of Update 2.